# how to conceptionally serve data to modern SPA frontends with PHP MVC backend?

Tags: php, angular, model-view-controller, single-page-application, vuejs2

I am not sure, what is conceptionally thought the right way to serve data from an php mvc backend to the frontend.

Basically, I was happy with the things in angularjs: Put some controllers into DOM and some directives for events like clicking, if conditions etc.. However, times have changed and we have to move on.

So here is my question: I have an huge PHP MVC backend with an template engine. And I would like to keep the things in place, because serving only json to the frontend would completely remove the View out of MVC.

Maybe serving some inner views as json would be ok. But I need the HTML structure to be served and prerendered by PHP. So mixed syntax with php template engine and angular. Let's take the example on angular or vue2 with TypeScript (that is what I prefer to use in my apps).

How to do this correctly to stay future-save? I mean this component style is nice, but I need to get it combined with my backend in smooth way. If I would just give an `templateUrl`, how could I make sure to use the full advantage of caching technologies and stuff like that from the frontend?

Answer (score 1):

Creating hybrid angular apps is a bit tricky because if handling state is tricky by itself in angular, try combining that with the state in php.

The best way I've found is to think of angular as a widget library.

By creating widgets (components) that contain do the heavy lifting UI wise you can come a long way.

I wouldn't try combining angular components templates with php, but instead pass data into the angular components. That way you can easily test the angular components and you will be able to reason about what is in angular land, and what is in hybrid land.
If you are debugging an angular component, you know it by checking the data coming into the component if the bug is in typescript or php.

A couple of scenarios.

### Form validation

You have a form that angular handles validation on, but then submit it using the normal `<form action="/submitform" method="post">`

### Advanced form

You have a more complex form possibly with multiple views where you handle post the data via a json api and angulars Http service.

### Graphs

Presenting data graphically via a graph widget.

## Howto

Make your whole php app an angular app but don't use angular's routing.

inject php state into components via `@Input()`

```
<my-component showinfo="<?= $showInfo ?>"></my-component>
```

By passing in all php variables via inputs you will be able to test the angular components easily via jasmine.

### angular-cli

I would probably use angular-cli to create the app. The problem there is that it defaults to use webpack dev server which only runs in memory.

Instead use

- --watch so that angular rebuilds when files change
- --output-hashing=none so that angular always outputs the same filenames so that you can include them in your app
- --output-path= to specify where you want the build files

  ng build --watch --output-hashing=none --output-path=my/php/public/folder

Comment: wow, thank you very much for that great answer. Do you have an example for it? Let's say we have an Symfony 3 app or something like that. How would you pass variables coming from controller actions into angular?

Comment: Sorry don't have an example. But as long as you can print the variables in the twig template you can pass them on to the angular component.

Comment: Ok, you mean I build an typescript / angular component, but I will use in the `HTML` template my php variables. So that the whole thing is typescript file with php in it, right?

Comment: No, you compile your angular app with angular-cli into a .js file that you include in your php app. The compiled angular app needs to bootstrap on the html tag so that we can use our components within the app. Then we use our angular components in the php code injecting php variables into the angular components via html attributes.

Comment: Well, I will build an example: A form with self-adding entries or something like that. But this may take a while. I think about one or two weeks. I will come back later and mark your answer as solved, if it does so.